# I trained a neural network but I cannot find where it got saved, I cannot find any .meta , .index, .data files

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, speech-recognition

I was trying to follow this page https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/sequences/audio_recognition

I successfully executed the following command:

python tensorflow/examples/speech_commands/train.py

I used a virtual environment in Anaconda. Used Tensorflow 14 and Python 3.6

It took about about 22 hours to train it. it said "/tmp/speech_commands_train/conv.ckpt-100" after every 100 iterations 
 (there were 18000 in total)

but now when I try to find conv.ckpt-18000.meta   or just speech_commands_train I cannot find it.

I am very new to this. This is my first effort in deep learning.

[how the terminal looked when training ended](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJjkN.png)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, what you mean by " Where It saved", by it you mean logs, the trained model or weights.

In your case, you are just storing the weights at given checkpoints hence you can acess them at given paths said in the tutorial

```
I0730 16:54:41.813438 55030 train.py:252] Saving to "/tmp/speech_commands_train/conv.ckpt-100"

*This is saving out the current trained weights to a checkpoint file. If your training script gets interrupted, you can look for the last saved checkpoint and then restart the script with -*
```

Also you can store logs using file writer and model using save_model or tensorboard callback with logdir.

Don't forget to upvote if found it useful